# Face Recognition using Kinect

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello , I am trying to make a face Recognition using kinect , First i download this package https://github.com/procrob/procrob_functional is there any way to recognize faces with this package but with using kinect ???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/158216/face-recognition-using-kinect/) by [smart engineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/15051/smart-engineer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to run that package with the kinect's camera topic instead of the gscam topic; it should be as simple as changing the topic remapping arguments.

The README does a very thorough job of describing how to download and run the node; the only thing you should have to do is change the topic remapping arguments

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [smart engineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/15051/smart-engineer/) on 2014-04-28**:
sorry I can't understand what You mean ???
Can You explain Your answer in steps ???